# How to start a call without triggering a prompt in BlackBerry 10 OS 10.3?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I am trying to initiate a phone call programmatically without the user being presented with the usual "Call ....?" prompt. According to the latest Momentics 2.1 summary of what is new in 10.3 "start[ing] an outgoing phone call without prompting the user" should be possible:

https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/momentics/

There doesn't seem to be any new permission for handling this though.

Does anyone know if making a programmatic 'prompt-less' call is indeed possible in 10.3 and if so what is the required permission?

Comment: Could you provide a more specific link? All the reading I have done on the phone API nothing indicates that you can initiate a phone call without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently starting a call programmatically without triggering a prompt is not (yet) possible.

It seems that the original statement that "start[ing] an outgoing phone call without prompting the user" was a misprint/slip-up in the 10.3 tooling documentation which was corrected shortly after the question was raised.

Here is the response from a senior BlackBerry rep Mark Sohm on the BlackBerry dev forums:

"That shouldn't have been listed yet.  Sorry for the confusion, I'll have that page updated accordingly."

Here is link to the thread in the BlackBerry forums:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/How-to-initiate-a-call-without-a-prompt-on-OS-10-3/m-p/2946146